# How to use curl with proxy and with japanese xml response

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I already have a working curl, but I can only test non-proxy sites.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But I need it to be able to connect through proxy(socks5) in my api, I can test this by using **firefox** and changing the proxy settings, the api returns an xml with japanese characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// connect using curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

// put the proxy settings here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxyHost);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,$proxyPort);

// connect with socks5
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// get the response and close curl connection
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Convert the return to xml object
$sXML = $data;
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);

// show it in the browser, this is optional.
echo '<pre>';       
var_dump($oXML);
echo </pre>;
```

Try this. Just remember, the `$oXML` is a **xml object**, you can get an object's children by using the **->** operator.